# IE 9 and styling the button element

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I have a button element where I apply a css class which adds border color to the various sides of the button.
This worked in the previous IE versions, but not in IE 9

```
HTML:

<button class="hello-button">Hello, World</button>

CSS:
.hello-button {     
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #eee #a9a9a9 #a9a9a9 #eee;
}
```

Is this a known issue and are there workarounds besides of the border-style: outset;
I have tried various combinations but it seems like you can not any longer style the borders of the button element.

**Edit: formating**

Comment: It seems that since the application is using frameset (legacy stuff ;)) IE9 will not render some styles properly. When I open the document outside of the frameset everything works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: or nope... setting border colors for button does not work in IE 9

Answer (score 5):

If you specify 3 of the borders, those borders will render in IE9.  Once you specify the 4th border, IE9 refuses to render any of the borders

**Works:**

```
.hello-button {     
    border-top: 2px solid #eee;
    border-right: 2px solid #a9a9a9;    
    border-bottom: 2px solid #a9a9a9;   
}
```

**Doesn't Work:**

```
.hello-button {     
    border-top: 2px solid #eee;
    border-right: 2px solid #a9a9a9;    
    border-bottom: 2px solid #a9a9a9;   
    border-left: 2px solid #eee;
}
```

Unless there's a valid (or at least spec'd) reason for this behavior, it looks like a bug to me...

Comment: very strange behavior. I´ve not figured out how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

This one is weird. It actually works if you don't specify border-style. IE9 will then give you a solid border, but other browsers will do all kinds of different things.

But it goes back to working if you specify border-radius (in addition to border-style).. So go on and treat yourself to some modern CSS styling :)

Of course this is not ideal if you want a perfectly square button, but you can set a low value for the radius (double check how it looks, though).

Answer (score 0):

It does look like a bug.  Can you define a document compatibility mode for an older version of IE?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a bug. Since I controll the server I solved it by setting a X-UA-Compatible response header to IE=EmulateIE8

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Servers

Comment: Forcing your browser to render a page in an outdated IE8 mode is just evil :-)